# is it possible to cast from iPhone to apple TV and HomePod?

Tags: appletv, streaming, homepod

I want to to be able to watch my Apple TV movie on my TV. I currently have Apple TV connected by HDMI to my Samsung TV and I also have a HomePod. I want to be able to stream the picture to the TV (possibly using the Apple TV device) and stream the audio to the HomePod. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

iPhone will airplay to the AppleTV which can select the HomePod(s) as the audio from AppleTV.

Comment: So technically you're not actually Airplaying to 2 devices. You Airplay to the Apple TV and that device, in turn sends the audio signal to the HomePod.  The iPhone will not send the audio to 1 device and video to a different device.  I wonder if you'll notice the audio and video will be slightly out of sync because of this?

Comment: @fsb no, Apple uses microphone arrays get the timing nailed for the exact rooms in my experience. HomePod are amazing. The playback is buffered to get the image and sound synchronous for streaming and movie downloads. I haven’t sniffed the traffic to see if it’s multicast but it just works in my experience